# Showcaseview for Long Press click - Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-gesture, showcaseview

I want to use `Showcaseview` in my android application to indicate `LongPress` gesture. I am using [ShowcaseView Library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) and i also reffered its sample demo app.I also searched for other sample application but couldn't get much idea.  As i am new to this concept, i don't know how i should use it to indicate long press gesture in my application.Please help me to solve this problem and give some suggestion or any tutorials regarding this topic.
Thank you.

Comment: Just to detect LONGPRESS, have you used this library??

Comment: I am using this library just to implement `ShowcaseView` functionality,but i don't know whether it provides any in-built `Longpress` animation or not.It provides facility of `Swipe` and `Click` events,but for `Longpress` does it provide any functionality? If you have used it then please help me for this issue.

Comment: Can u show me the code for Swipe and Click events??

Comment: For swipe  : `Showcaseview sv;sv.animateGesture(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: try with simple [GestureDetector](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_gestures.htm) to handle long press

Comment: Have you ever used `ShowcaseView` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41762/discussion-between-sweetwisher-and-zanky)

Comment: Anyone else figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial used for you check it

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_gestures.htm

Comment: You might got my question wrongly. I want to implement `ShowcaseView` for `Longpress`.